# Xamarin.Forms App (Android) hangs, cannot find out why

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

In a XAML view I have a switch, which is bound to the "Done" property of a class. I wanted to modify the setter of the "Done" property to log any the changes to a sqlite database.

The program hangs indefinitely without any message, when it calls the FindAsync() Method (see code snippet below). I have also tried other database related methods, like CreateTableAsync, and got the same hang.

Anyone having an idea what I am doing wrong, and what I can do to get what I want?

The xaml:

> ```
> <Switch HorizontalOptions="End" IsToggled="{Binding Done}" />
> ```

The code snippet

> ```
>     public bool Done
>     {
>         get { return _done; }
>         set
>         {
>             _done = value;
>             OnPropertyChanged();
>             Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Set attribute {0}: {1}", nameof(Done), value));
>             var itm = App.Database.FindAsync<LogItem>(Id).Result;
>             // Database.CreateTableAsync<LogItem>().Wait();
>             Debug.WriteLine("Back from find");
>             if (itm != null)
>             {
>                 // ...
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

The database connection:

> ```
>  private static SQLiteAsyncConnection database;         
>    public static SQLiteAsyncConnection Database
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             if (database == null)
>             {
>                 String dbPath = DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>().GetLocalFilePath(Constants.DatabaseName);
>                 Debug.Write(string.Format("{0}: {1}: ", nameof(Database), dbPath));
>                 database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
>                 Debug.WriteLine("Ok.");
>             }
>             return database;
>         }
>     }
> ```

Finally, here is the LogItem class

> ```
> public class LogItem
> ```

```
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }  // row name
    public string Input { get; set; }  // value
}
```

Comment: You need to `await` the async methods (the ones returning a `Task<T>`)

Comment: You saw the ".Result" at the end of the hanging command? The "done" method is not supposed to run async, I though it was safe to use .Wait() or .Result to make it run sync?

Comment: 1) `.Wait` and `await` are different in their context... 2) `.Result` is causing a **deadlock** on the thread since the continuation is scheduled now on a blocked thread (hopefully that is not the main/UI thread or your app will be terminated by the mobile OS) 3) To avoid all the related issues, `await` those async/Task based API methods... 4) Search SO, there are answers concerning `.Wait` and `.Result` issues from the authors/masters of C#.

Comment: @SushiHangover, you were perfectly right. Finally I got my async and await structure right, and the hang is gone.I's really like to award you some points, but how can I do so, I found no way to accept a comment as an answer.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it figured out. ;-)